# Minus Operand in Front Expression

Tags: java, parsing, calculator

### JAVA RPn Parser

`else if (token.equals("-")) {
op2 = stack.pop();
op1 = stack.pop();
stack.push(op2*-1);}`

if i input is "-4" or something with minus sign in front of number
it will bring error

Any idea?

Comment: What do you want? A simple parser that uses a stack for postfixed expressions?

Comment: Post more of your code and more over explain the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to parse negative numbers in RPN (Reverse Polish Notation) you will need to detect then in your parser before you push the number to the stack.

If you are reading a minus sign and the next symbol (before the space) is a digit, it will be part of the number. Take a look:

```
import java.util.*;

public class RPNParser {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        String rpnExp = "-4 3 + 5 * 3 - -61 *";
        String[] tokens = rpnExp.split( " " );

        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
        Integer op1 = null;
        Integer op2 = null;
        Integer result = null;

        for ( String token : tokens ) {

            if ( token.equals( "+" ) ) {
                op2 = stack.pop();
                op1 = stack.pop();
                stack.push( op1 + op2 );
            } else if ( token.equals( "-" ) ) {
                op2 = stack.pop();
                op1 = stack.pop();
                stack.push( op1 - op2 );
            } else if ( token.equals( "*" ) ) {
                op2 = stack.pop();
                op1 = stack.pop();
                stack.push( op1 * op2 );
            } else if ( token.equals( "/" ) ) {
                op2 = stack.pop();
                op1 = stack.pop();
                stack.push( op1 / op2 );
            } else {
                stack.push( Integer.valueOf( token ) );
            }

        }

        result = stack.pop();
        System.out.printf( "%s = %d\n", rpnExp, result );

    }

}
```

As you may know:

```
-4 3 + 5 * 3 - -61 * = ((((-4 + 3) * 5) - 3) * -61) = 488
        postfix                     infix             result
```

If you want to parse your String by hand (without using split) you will have some more work, but it is really easy.

```
String rpnExp = "-4    3 + 5 * 3 - -61 *";
StringBuilder newToken = new StringBuilder();
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();

for ( char c : rpnExp.toCharArray() ) {
    // the current char is a space?
    if ( c == ' ' ) {
        // yes, it is.
        // the new token has something?
        if ( newToken.length() > 0 ) {
            // yes, it has
            // add its value to the token list
            tokens.add( newToken.toString() );
            // resets new token
            newToken = new StringBuilder();
        }
    } else {   // c is not a space
        // yes, so add it to the newToken
        newToken.append( c );
    }
}

// needs to process the last value of newToken
// so, if it has something
if ( newToken.length() > 0 ) {
    // add the value to the token list
    tokens.add( newToken.toString() );
}

Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
// the rest of the code here ...
```